# Can Master step act like a Slave after sending partitioning messages while using MessageChannelPartitionHandler

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jms

I have created a small Proof of Concept(POC) using Spring Batch that uses MessageChannelPartitionHandler. The idea is to deploy the code on multiple nodes in production. My question is can the master node do the job of a slave also besides sending the partitioning messages to the slaves using messaging middleware like ActiveMQ. Is the master restricted to only sending the messages?

```
 @Bean
public Step masterStep() throws Exception {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
            .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), partitioner())
            .step(slaveStep())
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler(null))
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .gridSize(GRID_SIZE)               
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step slaveStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
            .<WorkItem, ReportData>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Profile("master")
public Job processingBatchJob() throws Exception {

    return 
   jobBuilderFactory.get("processingBatchJob").listener(jobListener)
            .start(masterStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("xtrac");
    return taskExecutor;
}    

@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(MessagingTemplate 
messagingTemplate) throws Exception
{
    MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new 
     MessageChannelPartitionHandler();
    partitionHandler.setStepName("slaveStep");
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(this.messageTemplate);
    partitionHandler.setPollInterval(5000l);
    partitionHandler.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);
    partitionHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
    return partitionHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the master can act as a worker in a remote partitioning setup and is not restricted to only sending messages to and aggregating results back from workers. I would even recommend to do it so that resources on the master node are not wasted waiting for workers to finish their work.

Comment: Can you share code snippets please. I could not locate on Spring site or on SO.

Comment: I don't have a ready to use example but you can make the master act as a worker by activating the worker's code in the master's application context (add the listener on the request queue). Another option is to use Spring Profiles (see [this repo](https://github.com/benas/scaling-demos/tree/sp1-2018) for examples) and launch the master with both the "master" and "worker" profiles.